# Why does leetcode give the error 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype, iterable

why does leetcode give the error 'NoneType' object is not iterable?

`Given a string s, find the length of the longest  substring without repeating characters.`

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        def select(s):
            list1 = []
            for i in s:
                if i not in list1:
                    list1.append(i)
                else:
                    return list1


        def select_list(st):           
            list2 = []
            list2.append(select(st))
            if len(st) > 1:
                st = (st[len(select(st))::])
                list2.append(select(st))
                return list2

        result = len(max(select_list(s)))
        return result
```

```
Runtime Error
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
    result = len(max(select_list(s)))
Line 20 in lengthOfLongestSubstring (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring(param_1)
Line 41 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 51 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I'm a beginner, I ask you not to kick too much for such a simple question
u not to kick too much for such a simple question
the code is executed but does not pass 'Submit'

Comment: Both your functions `select` and `select_list` may return `None` in certain conditions

Answer (score 0):

welcome.,

It's likely that the error is happening in your `select` function.

For example, if you pass `None` as an argument for s, then the error will be raised.

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        def select(s):
            list1 = []
            for i in s:
                if i not in list1:
                    list1.append(i)
                else:
                    return list1


        def select_list(st):           
            list2 = []
            list2.append(select(st))
            if len(st) > 1:
                st = (st[len(select(st))::])
                list2.append(select(st))
                return list2

        result = len(max(select_list(s)))
        return result

Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring(None) # will raise TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

+++++++++++++++++ EDIT +++++++++++++++++

Here is a solution using [sliding windows](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/)

```
class Solution:
    """Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters."""

    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        left, right = 0, 0
        seen: set[str] = set()

        longest_substr = 0
        while right < len(s):
            char = s[right]

            if char in seen:
                longest_substr = max(longest_substr, len(seen))
                while char in seen:
                    discard = s[left]
                    seen.remove(discard)
                    left += 1
            else:
                seen.add(char)
                right += 1

        return max(longest_substr, len(seen))
```

Comment: how can I fix the code?

Comment: @DmitryTrump For starter you want to check if the string, `s`, exists. Also, note that if the length of the string is less than or equals to 1, then the length of the string is the solution. In your `select` function, make sure that you return a list. i.e what if the for loop doesn't run for some odd reason? The `select_list` function is not consistent, sometimes it returns a list sometimes it returns a number, make it consistent. Either return a number or a list but not both. Look at my edit for a solution.